# Angular route creates 2 requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I have the following problem:

I have the following router for my angularJS app:

```
var app = angular.module('imagesApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'albums.html',
            controller  : 'imagesCtrl'
        })
        .when('/:genre', {
           templateUrl : 'albums.html',
            controller : 'genreCtrl'
        })
        .when('/album/:id', {
            templateUrl : 'product.html',
            controller : 'itemCtrl'
        });
});


app.controller('imagesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost/api/index.php/album")
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.images = response.data.msg.albums;
        });
});

app.controller('genreCtrl', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get("http://localhost/api/index.php/"+$routeParams.genre)
        .then(function (response) {
           $scope.images = response.data.msg.albums;
        });
});

app.controller('itemCtrl', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get("http://localhost/api/index.php/album/"+$routeParams.id)
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.product = response.data.msg.album;
        });
});
```

Everything works fine when I load http://localhost/ or http://localhost/#rock

But, when I try to load http://localhost/#album/1 or http://localhost/#/album/1, I see in my network tab at chrome debugger that there were two requests:

- GET /api/index.php/album/2 HTTP/1.1
- GET /album/2 HTTP/1.1

why such thing is happening?

Comment: Are you sure about the second GET request URL ? As per your config, when you hit the `localhost/#album/1` URL directly without loading anything first, 3 requests will be fired. (1) To get the actual home page with you app.js and ng-view which will embed your template (2) To get the JSON response from index.php for a given album id (3) To get the actual template (product.html) for your `/album/:id` route

Comment: Your question says that you're hitting `http://localhost/#/album/1` which means `id` is 1 but the request that you posted are talking about `/api/index.php/album/2`. I hope you meant to say `/api/index.php/album/1` here as well